# Visual Studio Live server responds to updates but github's real hosted website doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, css

#### **Problem**

I recently bought a website from google domains, I got my code running and tried to run a live server test using a visual studio extension I downloaded, It looked all right until I saw that the live server did look at my new button code. But when on my Github hosted website it didn't.

If anyone could help me work this out It will be a huge help to me and my website. I am new to both HTML, JS and even Github Pages. So sorry if this question is kinda easy to answer. I have some questions about the weird divs in my html, if anyone could anwser that too that would be great.

#### **Button Code**

```html
        <body>
          <nav class="upperpart"></nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li> 
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#Appeals">Appeals</a></li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#Store">Store</a></li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </body>
      </html>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Your `<div class="mc1inlineContent">` is covering the images. Right click => inspect. Debug

Comment: Which div class are you taking about, is it in the snippet or the full github page?

Comment: Is it this? ``    <div
      class="mc1inlineContent"
      style="width:100%;position:relative;top:0;bottom:0"
      id="comp-jzkh1ngp3inlineContent"
    >``